# Trying to connect Android app with SQLite to SQL Db via webservice (php)

Tags: php, android, sqlite, synchronization

To clarify on the problem; I'm following an old tutorial to try and learn some basic sync functionality with an Android app ([here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/)). Now I have the php webservice in place, I believe the permissions are set right, the POST in the Android code is set to the correct server IP. However when I try to synch the app to the SQL I am getting a AsyncHttpClient statusCode of 0. As far as I can tell, this means it is likely the request is timing out?

If so I'm looking for how to extend the timeout limit, if not then I am stuck and would appreciate any input from someone with an idea of where I'm going wrong. The code below is the relevant part from Android Studio.

```
public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB(){
    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
    if(userList.size()!=0){
        if(controller.dbSyncCount() != 0){
            prgDialog.show();
            params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
            client.post("http://46.105.118.169:9000/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if(statusCode == 404){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(statusCode == 500){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Practically speaking, status==0 for a failed XmlHttpRequest should be considered an undefined error.

Comment: Warning people against SQL injection-laden "tutorials" like this could turn into a daily hobby for me. Unfortunately he/she has just tweeted they have 10K "likes" on Facebook, so I may be just fighting against the tide.

Comment: Perhaps you could point me in the direction of a better resource for a similar process, halfer?

Comment: I'm not aware of one (I don't dev for Android). You want to look out for tutorials that use parameter binding, either with MySQLi or PDO/mysql. If you find one you like, ping it to me here (using @halfer please so I get notified) and I'll look at it.